# null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNPushNotification.createChannel')

Tags: android, react-native

**I got this error again and again. I do everything to solve this. It's perfectly linked with the library. And when I run this in an android studio it's successfully built and run Apk. Bt when I run code in developer mode like metro or Expo its shows this error.**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmhNd.jpg)